# unable to iterate over dataframes in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to arrange all dataframe columns in a specific sequence so i am performing the below:

```
df1 = df1.select("A", "B", "C", "D")
df2 = df2.select("A", "B", "C", "D")
df3 = df3.select("A", "B", "C", "D")
df4 = df4.select("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

But since i have multiple dataframes (around 20+), i am trying to turn it into a function that can be called:

```
def selection(df):
    df1 = df.select("A", "B", "C", "D")
    return df1
```

and then i am trying to perform iterations as follows:

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
for df in (df_list):
  selection(df)
  
df1.show()
```

But when i check the output of `df1.show()` its same as before the columns are still not ordered properly. I don't get any error too. I think i need to redirect the output of the for loop somewhere, maybe that's what is causing the issue but i need individual dataframes at the output.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the function on the list:

```
def selection(df):
    df1 = df.select("A", "B", "C", "D")
    return df1

df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
df_list = [selection(df) for df in df_list]

# or equivalently, 
# df_list = map(selection, df_list)
```

In the code you provided, you did not assign the output of the function to anything, so at the end nothing has been performed on your original list of dataframes.